# Including HTML in PHP mail Function

Tags: php, html, function, email

I have read a couple of posts on here about this already, so I know that I need to use the file_get_contents function to do this, but I have a bit more advanced need. I need to be able to call in data submitted by a user as well as call in the needed HTML to make the email look nicer. Here is some of my code:

First off, know the structure I have, inside index.php is my html form, and action="complete.php".

At the top of complete.php, I have this:

```
<?php 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $evaluator_email = $_POST["evaluator_email"];
    $teacher_email = $_POST["teacher_email"];
    $evaluator = $_POST["evaluator"];
    $teacher = $_POST["teacher"];
    $date = $_POST["date"];

        $teacher_body = "Hello " . $teacher . ", recently, " . $evaluator . " created a teacher evaluation for your session on " . $date . ". ";

    $evaluator_body = "Hello " . $evaluator . ", your evaluation of " . $teacher . " was successfully sent to " . $teacher_email . ". ";

    mail($teacher_email , "Evaluation" , $teacher_body , "From: $evaluator");

    mail($evaluator_email , "Evaluation" , $evaluator_body , "From: Teacher Evaluation Tool");
}

?>
```

Which all works fine, but now I want to be able to include HTML. How can I make $teacher_body and $evaluator_body equal a file that contains the HTML that I write, and still have access to the PHP variables such as $teacher, $evaluator, $date, etc?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp an example here

Comment: I've already read both of these without any luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use placeholders in situations like this. For example in the HTML file I'll put things like "TEACHER" and "EVALUATOR" etc. Then my PHP can be something along the lines of:

```
$html = file_get_contents("myFileWithPlaceholders.htm");
$html = str_replace ( "TEACHER", $teacher, $html );
$html = str_replace ( "EVALUATOR", $evaluator, $html );
```

Just make sure your placeholders are very unique and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try real quick.

Comment: It is not rendering the HTML, it is just giving the plain text with all of the tags showing up too.

Comment: OK so the next part is to set the headers correctly for the email, as mentioned in some other answers. Edit: for example <?php $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; ?>. Then send this with the email for example <?php mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); ?>

Answer (score 3):

**Example send an HTML email:**

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com, somebodyelse@example.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: As an addition to this, if you want style your HTML and add CSS, you have to do it inline. You cant hook up an external stylesheet, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly recommended to use PHPMailer.

https://phpbestpractices.org/#email

From this best practices website:

"PHP provides a mail() function that looks enticingly simple and easy. Unfortunately, like a lot of things in PHP, its simplicity is deceptive and using it at face value can lead to serious security problems.

Email is a set of protocols with an even more tortured history than PHP. Suffice it to say that there are so many gotchas in sending email that just being in the same room as PHP's mail() function should give you the shivers.

PHPMailer is a popular and well-aged open-source library that provides an easy interface for sending mail securely. It takes care of the gotchas for you so you can concentrate on more important things."

The library can be found here:

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Easy to use and works great for sending HTML and text-based emails!

Answer (score -1):

This is same as sending text in email. Just add the extra tags with a dot(.) operator.
For example:

```
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" .    strip_tags($_POST['req-name']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Type of Change:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['typeOfChange']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Urgency:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['urgency']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>URL To Change (main):</strong> </td><td>" . $_POST['URL-main'] . "</td></tr>";
$addURLS = $_POST['addURLS'];
if (($addURLS) != '') {
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>URL To Change (additional):</strong> </td><td>" .strip_tags($addURLS) . "</td></tr>";
}
$curText = htmlentities($_POST['curText']);           
if (($curText) != '') {
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>CURRENT Content:</strong> </td><td>" . $curText . "</td></tr>";
}
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>NEW Content:</strong> </td><td>" .htmlentities($_POST['newText']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";
// Always set headers
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

now send the email with:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```